# Selected radio button not working in iText.Html2pdf

Tags: c#, itext, itext7, html-to-pdf

I am trying to convert the following HTML to pdf, which has a preselected radio button with attributes checked. But it is throwing an error in `iTextSharp`.

```
<div style='color:#003399;font-style:italic;position:absolute;left:280px;top:170px;'>
<input type='radio' /><label> RD1 </label><br />
<input type='radio' checked /><label> RD2 </label> <br />
<input type='radio' /><label> RD3 </label><br />
</div>
```

my `C#` code is:

```
 public void createPdf()
        {
            string html = @"C:\Users\rahul\OneDrive\Desktop\new.html";
            HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(new FileStream(html, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read), new FileStream(DEST, FileMode.Create));
           
        }
```

the exception which I am getting is:

```
iText.Html2pdf.Exceptions.TagWorkerInitializationException: 'Could not instantiate TagWorker-class iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.Tags.InputTagWorker for tag input.'

   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultTagWorkerFactory.GetTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context)
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.Visit(INode node)
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.Visit(INode node)
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.Visit(INode node)
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.Visit(INode node)
   at iText.Html2pdf.Attach.Impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.ProcessDocument(INode root, PdfDocument pdfDocument)
   at iText.Html2pdf.HtmlConverter.ConvertToDocument(Stream htmlStream, PdfDocument pdfDocument, ConverterProperties converterProperties)
   at iText.Html2pdf.HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(Stream htmlStream, PdfWriter pdfWriter, ConverterProperties converterProperties)
   at iText.Html2pdf.HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(Stream htmlStream, Stream pdfStream)
   at ItextSharp.Program.createPdf() in D:\Console App\ItextSharp\ItextSharp\Program.cs:line 48
   at ItextSharp.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Console App\ItextSharp\ItextSharp\Program.cs:line 41
```

When the checked attribute on the radio tag is removed then it is working fine...

Comment: Could you provide the associated c# code so that people may try to reproduce?

Comment: just tried with [pdfHTML](https://itextpdf.com/en/demos/convert-html-css-to-pdf-free-online) (Html2Pdf) and the [result looks fine](https://i.ibb.co/zShtHm9/Captura-de-ecr-2021-06-07-135110.jpg). What error are you getting?

Comment: @XouDo . Modified the question with C# and exception.

Comment: @AndréLemos . I am facing the error when I add the checked attribute on Radio. Even I tried with selected and Checked='checked' it is not working. I need to show selected radio button. Checked attribute is working for checkbox input type. but not for radio type.

Comment: Please attach the full stacktrace, including the cause of `TagWorkerInitializationException`, as well as the versions of the libraries you are using

Comment: @AlexeySubach modified with full stack trace.

Comment: To Everyone , found the issue. We need a name attribute. Thanks all